# Running a script on startup for specific users on a linux vps

Tags: bash

How can i run a script everytime on start up, but for specific users? Like lets say i want to run 1 script on startup for the user (bob) and a differnt script or no script at all for the user (rick). Note: on a linux vps

Answer (score 1):

When `bash` starts, it will run the `/etc/bashrc` script for all users, then the `~/.bashrc` script for the specific user. Here `~` stands for the home directory of the user.

If you need something different for a few users, it is easier to use the second script (if you own those accounts.) In case you want to run something from a central point, then the first is better.

For the first approach, you can use the variable `$USER` to differentiate one user from another using `if` or `case` clauses. `$EUID` is safer because it is read-only, but that will give you the user id, not its name.

Using `case` at `/etc/bashrc` you could do:

```
case $USER in
  bob)
    <do something for bob>
    # No ";;" here so it follows through
  rick)
    <do something for bob and rick>
    ;;
  user9*)
    <do something for user9*>
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Is that script a bash script?

Comment: Yes, that is written in `bash`.

Comment: i get this error when running the script and yes i have added both users. "./test.sh: line 16: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
./test.sh: line 16: `  rick)'"

Comment: What´s the full content of line 16 of `test.sh`?

Comment: line 16 all it has is:   rick)

Comment: Have a look at the `case` syntax at the [bash reference manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs).

Comment: still dont get whats wrong with it

Comment: Publish the whole script and we will have a look at it